# General setter/getter methods for private properties

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I can create private members on a JavaScript class like this:

```
function Class(_foo, _bar) {
    var foo = _foo, // private, yay
        bar = _bar; // also private, also yay
}
```

How can I implement general setter/getter methods for this class? I suppose one way to do it would be to use `eval`:

```
function Class(_foo, _bar) {
    var foo = _foo,
        bar = _bar;

    this.get = function(property) {
        return eval(property);
    };

    this.set = function(property, value) {
        eval(property + " = " + value);
    };
}
```

However, this solution is ugly. Another way to do it is to create a `private` object and then access properties on that:

```
function Class(foo, bar) {
    var private = {
        foo: foo,
        bar: bar 
    };

    this.get = function(property) {
        return private[property];
    };

    this.set = function(property, value) {
        private[property] = value;
    };
}
```

I don't like this solution very much either, though, because it means I have to access the `private` object all over the place. Surely there's a cleaner way to provide a general getter/setter for private properties on a JavaScript class?

I realize similar questions have already been asked, but it doesn't appear that any of them ask this specific question; that is, how to provide a single getter/setter for all of the private properties on the class.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TbhF4/2/) with the two examples.

Comment: Your second example is usually how this is done.  There is no "master" object that you can use for local variables so you have to create one in order to access local variables like a property.  One certainly wonders why you have a public `.get(propName)` method for private properties though.  Doesn't it totally defeat the purpose of having private property names in the first place?  Of course, if you just put your properties on the `this` object, this would be easy.

Comment: @jfriend00 I want to call a specific function whenever I set a property on this class; seems like the best way to do that is to create a `set` function that both changes the property and calls that function. Naturally I don't want to be able to change the property manually, hence private variables. Hence `.get(propName)`. (I don't think watchers are supported well, if at all, yet)

Comment: What is the point of creating these getters/setters other than to make your JS more Java-like?  The implementation you are showing doesn't really hide any information since all variables are directly accessed through the getter and setter. This is the way things are often doen in Java, but it is not the JavaScript way.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg Please see my comment above.

Comment: I think you want to use ES5 getters and setters.  See answer below...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should be looking at ES5 getters and setters. These allow you to create things that look like properties, but really call functions behind them. For example:

```
var _a : 'nuthin',
var obj = {
  get a: function() { return this._a; },
  set a: function(a) { this._a = a; }
}

obj.a = 'sumpin';
console.log(obj.a); // nuthin
```

You can also create getters and setters inside of a constructor, but the syntax is clunkier.  Like this:

```
function nooObject(){
  var _a = 'nuthin';
  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    "a": { get: function () { return _a; } 
           set: function(a) { this._a = a; } }
  });
}
```

There are many more things you can do with `Object.defineProperties`.  Read all about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: I'm aware of getters and setters; however, I wasn't sure how well they were supported. If I want to support IE9+ and all other modern browsers going a few versions back, are they safe to use?

Comment: its worth mentioning that most people would probably find the [browser support](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Object.defineProperties) of this feature unacceptable(ie9+). Maybe in a few years though.

Comment: @rambocoder: That reference was what I was looking for, thanks. I think it's well-supported enough for my purposes. Wow. I didn't think setters and getters would come into play for another few years at least. This'll be fun.

Comment: Glad this will work for you. I often forget about legacy browsers since I am in a (lucky?) situation where I write developer tools for devs on the latest and greatest browsers.